# init() function in javascript definition and use

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding with javascript, and i encountered the function init(), i learned that it creates objects but i still dont even get what an object means, can someone explain to me whats init() and whats the use of it ? and why do we need to create objects with it and what is an object from the first place ?

```
function init() {
    refCode = document.getElementById("code");
    refVisuel = document.getElementById("cadreVisuel");
    document.getElementById("version").innerHTML += " " + version;
}
```

Comment: It is a function. A function can be called. There is no "special `init()` function" in JavaScript. What it does and how its used is up to you

Comment: i see ! thanks alot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, it is an arbitrary function name. It has no special meaning beyond its [normal English definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/initialize).

> Set to the value or put in the condition appropriate to the start of an operation.

---

> i learned that it creates objects

It does not.

It searching the document for two elements (by their ids) and assigns them to variables.

Then it modifies the content of a third element to append a variable (which doesn't otherwise appear in this example) to it.

> i still dont even get what an object means

An object is a representing of any piece of data more complex than a primitive. Arrays are objects. HTML Elements are objects. strings, numbers, booleans, and a couple of other things are not.